# Conceito de implementação de um RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para android nativo e estou em duvida quanto a melhor forma de implementar o seguinte comportamento:

- Tenho uma RecyclerView que lista diversos itens (obvio né), no entanto eu quero que, quando eu segurar um destes items abra uma sub tela com características deste item.

A forma mais precisa de realizar isto até agora na qual consigo pensar é carregar cada item da recyclerView com **dois layouts**, sendo um invisível (GONE) e o outro visível, quando ocorresse o **longClick** iria substituir os layouts.
Creio que teria certa dificuldade em posicionar o item em evidencia no topo da recyclerView, de forma que ele apenas saísse dessa tela quando fosse minimizado.
Outra ideia seria substituir todo o recyclerView por um novo layout.

Minhas duvidas principais são:

- Ter um layout mais complexo (mesmo que invisível) pode impactar muito se ele estiver em cada item de uma recyclerView, sendo muitos itens possíveis?
- Eu consigo fazer um bom controle da posição de item na recyclerView, manter o item expandido sempre na tela visível, sem deixar o usuário dar scrool?

grato

Comment: https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/ :p

Comment: A abordagem normal é ter dois fragments. Um para a lista e outra para o detalhe(características). Em telas pequenas, o fragment do detalhe substitui o fragment da lista, quando um item é escolhido. Em telas maiores, eles são apresentados lado a lado ou um por cima do outro.

Comment: @ramaral Até o momento estava fazendo algo similar, estava substituído o recyclerView por um novo layout.
Já estou usando o expandableListView, mas gostei da ideia do  expandablerecyclerView. 
Agradeço

Comment: @ramaral 
Implementei expandable rv do bignerdranch.
Gostaria de saber se você poderia me ajudar. pretendo colocar um recyclerview dentro do expandable recyclerview, no entando, não consigo chamar o "inflate" do rv dentro do child.

Comment: Suponho que isso não seja possível. No entanto faça uma nova pergunta com o código que tentou.